# how to set up an cluster server for minecraft hosting?

Tags: server, cloud, minecraft, hosting

I want to know how to make an hpc cluster server to host minecraft

I want to use this server for gaming and other Ubuntu desktop tasks

I want to use vnc for this server to log in anywhere on the world
and control the minecraft console

please explain to me step for step how to do this

because I still have a few old computers lying around, and get some for free from a friend.

greetings berrylee32 (minecraft name)

Comment: Cluster != server. Very different systems.

Comment: wtf i mean an hpc cluster for minecraft hosting is an cluster server combined definitions!!!!!

Comment: Yes, but you can't just plug in a network cable to each machine and expect Minecraft to magically run as if it were a clustered server. A cluster is a network topology and a form of infrastructure. "Clustered" applications and services are designed to work in a distributed system. Minecraft server is a generic server application that's designed to run on a single PC.

Comment: i already know that but i want to get all of the power combined of those old machines and use it for minecraft hosting
i want to make an cluster and use it therefore so i could use the combined power of these pc's and i want to know if the cluster is set up i have to use an vm for the whole system to work or just the system itshelf

Comment: you *can't* do that - there's no way to distribute a single arbitrary process across multiple machines. Software has to be designed with this in mind, and Minecraft isn't

Answer (score 1):

http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/High-Availability_Cluster
y n google? its even the official resource

Comment: eh sorry i think you didnt understand me, it has to be an hpc cluster for the performance of multiple machines together.        and how to use it for the minecraft software, and for on remote controlling becouse i have experience with vnc.
not that kind of HA server that is not what i wanted          
greetings berrylee32